# Reset hidden value of a form in mvc using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two forms in a single view and when clicking on a button outside the forms I use jQuery to submit the form based on selection, and I need to pass a value to controller.

I am adding hidden field using below code to a form

```
$('#myform').append("<input type='hidden' name='option' value='myval' />");
```

How do I clear and reassign value to this hidden field using jQuery for each submit?

Comment: Can you please put more content to understand your requirement?

Comment: @YogeshSharma edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Assign a id for this element:

```
$('#myform').append('<input type="hidden" id="my-id" name="option" value="myval" />');
```

Use id selector to assign new value.

```
$('#myform #my-id').val('new val');
```

By the way, your append string have syntax error (quotes)